# MMQGIS Geocoding Certificate Error

Tags: qgis, python, geocoding, mmqgis

I am trying to geocode a couple of addresses, but I keep getting a "failure to connecting to API" error. I received my API key from signing up with Thunderforest, and I also installed certificates through my Python shell, but I still seem to keep getting this error. I installed the latest pip, and I have over 1000 data points, so I think it may be the reason, but I am not too sure.

[image]